# d3.js nested selection i can't build my group

Tags: json, d3.js, nested, selection

I want use the nested selection. 
I read a [Nested Selection tutorial](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/nest/) already.
but, i don't understand.

i want a group like this.

```
<g>
    <text>name</text>
    <rect>FAVORABLENESS bar</rect>
    <rect>FRIENDLINESS bar</rect>
</g>
<g>
    <text>name</text>
    <rect>FAVORABLENESS bar</rect>
    <rect>FRIENDLINESS bar</rect>
</g>
```

code :

```
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg").attr("height",h).attr("width",w);
var groups = svg.selectAll("g").data(data).enter().append("g");
```

what shoud i do?

my data is

```
[
 {
   "name":"SeHyeon",
   "FAVORABLENESS":[
    {
      "myphoto_like":0,
      "myphoto_comment":0,
      "myWall_like":0,
    }
    ],
    "FRIENDLINESS":[
    {
      "myphoto_tag":0,
      "myWall_nametag":0,
    }
    ]
 },
 ....
]
```

Comment: The DOM should follow the data structure. What does your data look like?

Answer (score 0):

```
var d = [
 {
   "name":"SeHyeon",
   "FAVORABLENESS":[
    {
      "myphoto_like":0,
      "myphoto_comment":0,
      "myWall_like":0,
    }
    ],
    "FRIENDLINESS":[
    {
      "myphoto_tag":0,
      "myWall_nametag":0,
    }
    ]
 }
 ];

var svg = d3.select(".container")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", 300)
    .attr("height", 300);

var g = svg.selectAll("g")
    .data(d) // jon elements of d to generate d.length g
    .enter().append("g")
.attr("data-name", function (d) { return d.name; });

var fav = g.selectAll(".fav")
    .data(function (d) { return d.FAVORABLENESS; })
    .enter().append("rect")
    .attr("class", "fav");

var fri = g.selectAll(".fri")
    .data(function (d) { return d.FRIENDLINESS; })
    .enter().append("rect")
    .attr("class", "fri");
```

the two article in d3 explain selection perfect so you can read it repeated and exercise with the article

http://bost.ocks.org/mike/selection/

http://bost.ocks.org/mike/nest/

i write a simple sample with your data to illustrate nest selection and data join

you can inspect the dom structure with your browser develope tool.

http://jsfiddle.net/6PZ3t/